# Mysql find match of very short string?

Tags: mysql

I need to find all occurences of 'Of' (case sensitive) in table `Cities`.

I'm trying with match and I also tried with like but none works.

```
SELECT * FROM `Cities` WHERE MATCH(`Name`) AGAINST ('Of')
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `ft_min_word_len` directive to 2 in this case. The default value is 4, so 1, 2 and 3 letter words aren't indexed.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

It should work with `LIKE` though. Make sure you tried something like this:

```
WHERE `name` LIKE BINARY '%Of%'
```

PS: missed requirement about case sensitive - so added `BINARY` for that

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `Cities` WHERE `Name` COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%Of%'
```

`COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI` is for case sensitive.